# Word 2013 page numbering: use non-English alphabet

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, page-numbers, multilingual

Word 2013 offers a page numbering format of the type A, B, C, D, ..., etc (as opposed to numbering like 1, 2, 3 or i, ii, iii).

I'd like to replace it with another alphabet. Is that possible?

Comment: Which alphabet? For example, if you add Hebrew support to Office you'll get two additional number formats using Hebrew letters.

Comment: oh I see, thanks @Atzmon, how do you add support for additional languages? I will need a few different, Polish, Hungarian, etc

Comment: I don't know if Word offers number formats using these languages alphabet (I know it does for Arabic and Hebrew). It may require you to purchase a language pack so I would check first with Microsoft, or see if someone here on SuperUser can confirm that's the way to get those formats.

Comment: i was able to add it for from Options -> Language -> Edit Language. Under heading Keybard Layout it says "Enabled" and under Proofing it says "Installed". Does that constitute a full installation of a language pack, or I need to do something extra?